# Order by max value of a joined table in group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to complete my query of 4 tables

- Images : id
- Tags: id,name
- TagImages : image_id, tag_id (foreign key to images and tags)
- ColorImages : image_id , hex, value (foreign key to images)

I want to get similar images that have tags and colors in common . The images should have at least one in common tag but order by similar colors.

I have written the tags similarity query like this:

```
SELECT TagImages.imageId , count(*) AS q
FROM TagImages 
Join colorImages ON colorImages.imageId = TagImages.imageId
WHERE TagImages.tagId IN (
    SELECT TagImages.tagId 
    FROM TagImages 
    WHERE TagImages.imageId=41
) 
AND TagImages.imageId!=41 
GROUP BY TagImages.imageId 
ORDER BY q DESC
```

It works fine, but it need to add color 'order by' that sort images with the colors of target image. ColorImages table has a column named value that represents the percentage of that color in the image, so it is better to sort images with the highest valued colors.

Comment: What is the relation Image to colorImages ? 1:1, 1:n, m:n? What is the defintion of "similar Image"?

Comment: 1:n  - each image has some colors

Comment: Can you explain the where clause you need all imageid=41 and outside subquery you said imageid !=41, what is that mean? it is either =41 or not = 41, second add that column from colorImages table in select and include it in order by. If I can see the data or table structure can write the exact sql

Answer (score 0):

Well without looking into table structure and data I could present this and it should work, if you put table structure with little bit data script so we can play with it and can bring the result required.

```
SELECT TagImages.imageId , count(*) AS q, ColorImage.value
FROM TagImages 
Join colorImages ON colorImages.imageId = TagImages.imageId
WHERE TagImages.imageId=41 
GROUP BY TagImages.imageId, ColorImage.value 
ORDER BY q DESC, ColorImage.value
```